# WebView Android Studio com HTML5

Tags: android, html5, webview

Como que deixa um layout 100% responsivo em WebView? Eu tenho que configurar na WebView ou e o meu HTML que não esta Responsivo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);

}
```

Comment: Você tem que verificar se seu html é responsivel... não tem como a gente saber porque não pode ser reproduzido aqui por falta de código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce tem de configurar diretamente no html via style css, algo tipo isso:

```
<head>
<title>teu titulo da tua pagina</title>
<!-- ... -->
<!-- tem de ter isso no seu html -->
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
      charset='utf-8'>
<!-- faltou essa linha de código, foi maus... -->
<!-- -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<script src='bootstrap/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='bootstrap/js/jquery-scrolltofixed.js'></script>
<link href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<style type="text/css">
/* For desktop: */
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
  //
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  [class*="col-"] {
      width: 100%;
  }
  //
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
  }
  /* reset de margens */
  /* para garantir que estes elementos ocuparão toda a tela */
  body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  }
</style>
</head>
```

deve também carregar os script's e styles do bootstrap, caso seja com ele que voce esteja trabalhando.
deve também acrescentar essa linha para o webview:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

tenta ai, avisa se funcionou.

[EDIT] - a linha comentada acima é necessária.
Como especifiquei nos comentários, eu busco as configurações para o bootstrap diretamente no root da minha html, pode ver que os links são para a tal pasta 'src=bootstrap/...'.
Espero que funcione agora

Comment: infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: voce colocou o código dentro das tags html corretas, tipo `<style type="text/css"> o coding aqui ...</style>` ?

Comment: sim defini as tegs <style> e também crie um arquivo e especifiquei o caminho dele pela teg <link> mais sem sucesso .  Não existe alguma outra configuração a fazer pois sou novato no assunto e posso ter deixado de fazer.

Comment: aqui funcionou redondinho, mas eu coloquei uma pasta com o bootstrap diretamente na minha pasta assets, tem inclusive uma app rodando na loja com esse código ai

Comment: vou editar a reposta, dai voce olha ok

Comment: Armando e esse seu código me ajudou muito , ficou bom depois que eu coloquei a teg <meta > mais quando eu giro o celular ele não ajusta a tela do lado esquerdo fica em branco ainda , como a imagem acima mais a tela de login aproximou .

Comment: faltou um configuração no Activity_main.xml que tava como  android:layout_width="368dp"                         
android:layout_height="495dp"                                                                             e  eu coloquei:                                  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"                                                        mais a sua resposta foi de muita ajuda muito obrigado Armando.

Comment: vota como reposta certa, ajuda ae nuns pontinhos também